# Netlify serverless function wont import this package. Leaves it as undefined

Tags: serverless, netlify, gun

```
import Gun from 'gun'
import SEA from 'gun/sea'
```

`Gun` imports and works as expected, but `SEA` is set to undefined, when it should be an object

Notes:

- `SEA` gets imported correctly on the client, and in my IDE. Netlify is the only side thats struggling
- Netlify does not throw a `could not resolve` error
- I'm running this on a local dev server, if that matters

Things I've tried:

- reinstalling it
- importing it like this: `import Gun, {SEA} from 'gun'`
- Using node imports instead of ES6

All have had no effect

Please help, ty

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
Just needed to add this to the config toml

```ini
[functions]
external_node_modules = ["gun"]
```